# Wordpress contact form 7 cannot send another email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have set up [Contact Form 7](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) extension on a wordpress site and we've found some very strange behavior:

The contact form works when the user first reaches the page, the email is actually sent and the feedback is successful.

But if the user tries to send another email, it then fails at SMTP level:

I get:

> There was an error trying to send your message.

like mentioned [there](https://contactform7.com/faq/after-submitting-the-form-i-get-an-error-message/) but on the wp-admin side, I have:

```
Mailer: Autre SMTP
SMTP Error: data not accepted.
```

Is this by design? This should be documented then. I tried to search for this issue, but google results are spammed with delivery config issues.

Is this some kind of spam filtering technique?

Is this that the state of the form is not properly reset after first send?

Anyway, help would be much appreciated.

I use wordpress 5.7, contact form 7 version 5.4 and WP Mail SMTP version 2.6.

Cheers

Comment: Check your console for hints, and specially, the Network tab. Open it, refresh the page and try to reproduce. Errors will be highlighted in red. Click on it and see the Response Tab on the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks I'll investigate further but I was first wondering if anyone reproduces the issue with his own WP instance

Comment: what do you mean by the "the user sends another email"?  Are you referring to the CF7 option to send a 2nd notification mail to a different address?